# Package Structure (and where to place images)

Tags: java

I'm self taught, and while trying to load an image with getClass().getResource(path) I think I've highlighted a problem with how I structure my projects. I currently just use cmd and TextPad.

My folder structure is as follows:

Desktop/Java/uk/co/woodward/recruit

```
    /build
    /images
    /src
```

I compile from the Java folder in command prompt using 
`javac -d "." uk/co/woodward/recruit/src/example.java`

The .java files are in `package  uk.co.woodward.recruit.build;`

This all works fine and classes end up in the build folder, but while reading how to use icons in the java trail I realised that "build" isn't a package and I'm a little confused about how to set the location of an image file relative to the current class. I'm also unsure of whether I should set 'Java' (or recruit) as a root variable/path of some sort, rather than just compiling from there.

Anyway, nothing I've tried so far has worked.

```
public CandidateFormToolBar(){
    saveButton.setIcon(createIcon("/images/save.png", "Save"));
    add(saveButton);
}

private ImageIcon createIcon(String path, String btnName){
    URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
    if(url == null)
        System.err.println("\nThe " + btnName + " Icon Path Cannot Be Found: " + path + "\n");

    return new ImageIcon(url);
}
```

When running the program I've tried having the image in the build folder with the classes and using the path "save.png", I've tried the above code (which I thought would go up a level to the recruit folder and then to the image folder), with no luck. I've tried using -cp to point the jvm to the images folder. And much more.

And the outcome is that I've realised I **still** don't understand this well enough, and that my structure probably isn't recommended. Which is slightly depressing!

If anyone could point me vaguely in the right direction it would be appreciated!

Comment: Oh you are kidding me. It's now working.

It was a case of Windows hiding extensions from me on that one file, but not every other file in the folder.

I'd still appreciate feed back on the structure of my packages if anyone would mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your images inside the folder where you have put your Java files. Like in case of tomcat server this is the structure I use for accessing images in my jsp files.

```
>>Web content
   >imagesfolder 
   >Web-inf
  Myfile.jsp
```

Now in this Myfile.jsp file for accessing images from imagefolder I use following url "imagesfolder/myimage.png". Here Web content is the folder which have Myfile.jsp and 2 sub folder imagesfolder and web-inf and imagesfolder contains myimages.png

You can also make a directory like this if your file are in Java folder then create a image folder in that and access them using the url pattern mentioned above.

Hope this solve your query.

Comment: That structure looks like the Web-inf, rather than Webcontent folder contains the Myfile.jsp. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: so you'd recommend putting the images in a subfolder of the content folder, which I'd guess would be the equivalent of my 'build' folder (the one containing my class files rather than my .java source files). makes sense. thanks